# Merge Lists and "merge" sorting

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting, ienumerable

I have a List of List's that I'm trying to figure out how to merge them into one unqiue list, except I also want to take into account the sorting of each list currently.

Ex:

```
List<List<string>> ListofLists = new List<List<string>>();
ListofLists.Add(new List<string>() { "Color", "Size", "Dimensions" });
ListofLists.Add(new List<string>() { "Color", "Size", "Dimensions" });
ListofLists.Add(new List<string>() { "Color", "Size", "Weight", "Dimensions" });
```

I want the contents of the "merged" list to be:

> Color, Size, **Weight**, Dimensions

I've looked Unions but this adds "Weight" to the end of the list -- I want it to "merge" the lists keeping the "extra" values inline (as much as possible).

I also found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577882/how-to-merge-2-sorted-listed-into-one-shuffled-list-while-keeping-internal-order) which is close but it seems to insert the 'extra' value at a random point.

Sorry if this isn't explained well, I don't really know how to describe this.

**Edit**:  The goal of this is to place multiple products on a single table and list their specs beneath, showing similar specs on the same row.  Some products might have different specs but for the most part they are the same.

So I'm trying to generate a single list of the possible Spec names to show in the first column.  Typically the specs at the end are related to warranty, at the top related to models, etc.  So if Product 3 has some weird spec I would rather have it inserted inline somewhere than tacked on the end under warranty.

Example output:

```
Model #    | 123 | 456 | 789
Color      | red | red | blue
Size       | big | big | small
Weight     |     |     | 3
Dimensions | 1"  | 1"  | 1"x1"x1"
Warranty   | 1   | 2   | 3
```

Probably not the best example, but for instance maybe 123 and 456 don't have a Weight spec.  So rather than tack Weight on at the bottom (which is happening when I do a Union) I'd like it to be as close to "inline" with it's original list as possible.  You can't see in this example but each product might have 30 specs, so it's desirable to have the important ones on top as their List of Specs reflects.

Comment: is it possible to see some ideal input-output values?

Comment: What if the 4th list contained "Size", "Price", "Weight", "Quantity"?  I know that's arbitrary, but really hard to come up with any kind of algorithm without accounting for all cases.

Comment: This is non-trivial.  If you go through each list and have Color, Size, Dimensions / Weight, how does the algorithm decide at that point whether it should be Weight or Dimensions next (other than the order of the operands, which is what Union() does

Comment: @Marc I thought about that, but I guess I'm looking for any options. I suppose since all the values are in the first list it would stick with the order of the first.

Comment: @TomF: If you want to stick with the order of the first list first, then `Union()` is what you want...  It keeps the ordering of the first list and adds unique elements from the second...

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare Yep Union does what I want except it tacks the items from the second list onto the bottom of the resulting list, I want them to be inserted in the new list around their corresponding items in the current list.

Comment: I edited post with an example that might help explain what I'm after...maybe .. :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a graph of the ordering of each of the elements in the lists. (So for ACDEFGHJ, ABDFGHIJ, ABCDEGIJ you would get A->C, A->B, C->D, B->D, B->C, etc.) Hopefully only one node will have no inward arcs (in this case A); add this element to your resulting list. Remove that node and its outward arcs, and repeat the process. If you have multiple nodes with no inward arcs, then you can choose one at random. If you have no nodes with no inward arcs, then you have a cycle. You could break the cycle by choosing a member at random, but you would have to find the cycle first...

Comment: This sounds right but is way over my head, thanks though.  I ended up re-working this to maintain a separate list of the correct sortorders and use that to sort my specs.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the LINQ Concat and Distinct extension methods. They should be able to help you accomplish what you're after.

Comment: Thanks, I tried those but they are tacking the "extra" items at the bottom of the new list.  Anyway I figured out a different solution using a separate static list that contains all the specs and maintains their sort order, and using that to sort by union'ed list.